# tmuxのDefault key binding(Ctrl-b) が有効でない

Tags: tmux

sessionのwindowをショートカットキーを使って縦分割(Ctrl-b %)　横分割(Ctrl-b “)したいのですが、tmuxの[Default key binding(Ctrl-b)](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#DEFAULT_KEY_BINDINGS) が有効でないと思われ、縦分割(Ctrl-b %)　横分割(Ctrl-b “)が出来ません。

**環境**
Mac OSX 10.13.6
tmux 2.8
Homebrewでインストール。`$ brew install tmux`

`~/.tmux.conf`の設定ファイルは初期のデフォルト状態で、触っていません。
設定ファイルの中身は空でした。

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf
```

コマンドでPrefix keyを確認

```
$ tmux show-options -g prefix
prefix C-b
```

ターミナルはMacOS内蔵のterminalを使用してます。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `~/.tmux.conf` の設定はどうなっていますか？ また、ターミナルとして何を使っていますか？ tmux はどのように起動していますか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tmux を初めてお使いでしょうか？　[Ctrl-b + c, %, n, w, etc not working in tmux console - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/928702/770598) にあるとおり `ctrl-b` を押したら両方のキーをいったん離して、他の文字（`"` や `%`）を押すようにしてください。

それ以外の場合、ちょっと難しいですね…… どういう状況か確認してみてください。

- ターミナルが `ctrl-b` を送れているか：
  新しい（tmux を実行していない）ターミナルウィンドウで `od -tx1 -An` を実行し、`ctrl-b` `ctrl-d` `ctrl-d` をタイプし、

  ```
  ^B           02
  ```

  のように `02` が表示されれば `ctrl-b` をターミナルがプログラムに送れている。
- tmux を使っているか：
  `tmux list-sessions` を実行し、

  - `no server running on /private/tmp/tmux-501/default` などと表示されたら実は tmux を実行できていない。
  - 行の後ろに `(attached)` とあれば、tmux を表示しているターミナルがある。
  - それ以外の行は、生きているけど表示（アタッチ）されていないセッション。